# Possible Invalid cross-thread access?

Tags: c#, silverlight, exception, mvvm, multithreading

I've encountered a rare issue in the application I'm working on. This occurs on rare occations, but not neccesarily every time I'm navigating between pages, and I can't seem to wrap my head around it. Been reading around, and drawn to a semi-conclusive theory that this might be related to invalid cross-thread access. Stacktrace is as follows:

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException, mscorlib, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e  Message: [Arg_TargetInvocationException]
Arguments: 
Debugging resource strings are unavailable. Often the key and arguments provide sufficient information to diagnose the problem. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=106663&Version=5.0.10411.00&File=mscorlib.dll&Key=Arg_TargetInvocationException HelpLink: 
StackTrace:    at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.EndLoad(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationService.ContentLoader_BeginLoad_Callback(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.BeginLoad_OnUIThread(AsyncCallback userCallback, PageResourceContentLoaderAsyncResult result)
   at System.Windows.Navigation.PageResourceContentLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.<BeginLoad>b__0(Object args)
2013-02-01 15:56:43,593 [5640] DEBUG WellguideViewModel.class - RefreshGraphValues method called
MachineName:2013-02-01 15:53:53,548 [5640] DEBUG WellViewModel.class - WellViewModel constructor called
MachineName:2013-02-01 15:56:44,625 [1836] DEBUG WellguideViewModel.class - RefreshGraphValues method called
```

Hopefully, somebody will be able to help :)

-- Also, I should probably mention that my component is drawing some lines (PathFigure to be specific) on a canvas, as I've understood that this issue might be related to drawing of ui elements.

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Glad to help, but not nearly enough information to work with here. We need concrete details.

Comment: Can you construct a minimal reproduction of the code that causes this exception?

Comment: I'd love to, but the problem is the randomness of this. I really don't know where it's coming from.

Comment: Your error just seems to be an uncatch low level error. Now if you suspect a cross thread, would you detail the architecture of your code? Probably some asynchronous call? Do you carefully manage the callback and check they are running on the good thread? (UI thread if you want to draw something?)

Comment: Hi,

At the moment, this issue has been assigned to another developer. I will get back to this thread with the solution once it's done.
For the time being, thanks :)